# Is there a standard methodology and tool for mapping data to FHIR objects?

Tags: hl7-fhir

We have data stored in a standard flat file format (and even possibly in a relational database) that need to be mapped to FHIR resources.  I'm wondering if there is a standard methodology and/or tool for doing data mapping to FHIR with the ability to track changes being made?

Answer (score 2):

There's no particular "standard" methodology or tools for doing this.  FHIR offers (but does not require the use of) the StructureMap resource which allows documenting and executing the mapping of two arbitrary data structures.  The HL7 IGPublisher allows executing these mappings, but there's no HL7 or open source tool for authoring I'm aware of.  The [Open Mapping Software](http://www.openmapsw.com/FHIR/FHIR.htm%20%22Open%20Mapping%20Software) tool has a user interface for defining mappings that can be converted to StructureDefinitions as well as to executable Java code.  However, to my knowledge, most implementers just code their own tranformations or use an interface engine capable of mapping flat files to XML and/or JSON syntaxes.